# Deprecated field [disable_coord] used, replaced by [disable_coord has been removed]

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, .net-core, graylog3

I don't know if this a good question or not. I've never worked on elastic search before.

I'm getting "[WARN ][o.e.d.c.ParseField       ] [vLJycm6] Deprecated field [disable_coord] used, replaced by [disable_coord has been removed]" in the docker output log when I start running the elastic search container. I'm using this container for graylog3.

Do I need to be concerned about this "warning" from ElasticSearch?

This is code is part of docker compose file

```
mongodb:
    container_name: mongodb
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: on-failure
    networks:
      - dev
    volumes:
      - mongodbdata_dev:/data/db
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'

  elasticsearch:
    container_name: elasticsearch
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:6.6.1
    volumes:
      - elasticsearchdata_dev:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - dev
    environment:
      - http.host=0.0.0.0
      - transport.host=localhost
      - network.host=0.0.0.0
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1

  graylog:
    container_name: graylog
    image: graylog/graylog:3.0
    volumes:
       - graylogdata_dev:/usr/share/graylog/data
    networks:
      - dev
    environment:
      - GRAYLOG_PASSWORD_SECRET=somepasswordpepper
      - GRAYLOG_ROOT_PASSWORD_SHA2=somesha
      - GRAYLOG_HTTP_EXTERNAL_URI=http://127.0.0.1:9000/
    links:
      - mongodb:mongo
      - elasticsearch
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
      - elasticsearch
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
      - 1514:1514
      - 1514:1514/udp
      - 12201:12201
      - 12201:12201/udp
```

Please let me know if you need any other information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Graylog still has some option for elasticsearch 5 and since you're using 6+, it's complaining.But no harm done until Elasticsearch 5 support is removed from graylog.So ignore for now

Comment: Thanks alot Duane Barker.